# read a sequence file (with snappy compression) from hdfs remotely?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

My local OS is Ubuntu 14.04.
i want to remotely connect to my Hadoop cluster and read from HDFS by below sample code.
files that i need too read have snappy compression codec.

```
public static void readFromSequenceFile(String filePath){
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.default.name" , "hdfs://master.cluster:8020");
    Path path = new Path(filePath);
    try(FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, path, conf)){
        Writable key = (Writable)ReflectionUtils.newInstance(reader.getKeyClass() , conf);
        Writable value = (Writable)ReflectionUtils.newInstance(reader.getValueClass(), conf);
        long position = reader.getPosition();
        while(reader.next(key , value)){
            boolean sync = reader.syncSeen();
            System.out.println(position + " - " + sync);
            position = reader.getPosition();
        }
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but i got the following error:

> WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
>
> WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>
> WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: native snappy library not available

Comment: your ubuntu system having all the config files as hadoop cluster having?

Comment: no, but which config do you meaning?

Comment: are you using command line or eclipse to run these codes?

Comment: i use intellij idea

Comment: have you added all jars to your project?

Comment: i guess you need to add confiq files to project to run on local, config files means like hdfs-site.xml

Comment: i add all jars that need to write a map reduce program but i don't know how to add config files like hdfs-site.xml. how these files can help to compile and run time execution errors.

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/85757/how-to-add-the-hadoop-and-yarn-configuration-file.html

Comment: it is for spark but you can do the same approach for your project also